# Inside a section header, words generated by \NewDocumentCommand doesn't appear on the bookmark's browser of the final pdf. output

Tags: pdf, section-titles

The following code produces expected output for the final pdf. But the appearance of the bookmark browser on the pdf is wrong if the header contains a word generated with the \NewDocumentCommand. All is fine with the old command \newcommand.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{foo\xspace} 
\newcommand{\fooo}{}{fooo\xspace} 

\begin{document}
\section{A section about \foo}
\section{Another section about \fooo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please fix your example, you forgot to load the `xspace` package. Note that it is generally not recommended to use `\xpsace`, it is better to write ``\foo\ `` when needed

Comment: And the syntax for `\newcommand` is wrong. Perhaps you should make sure your example compiles before posting.

Comment: Thirdly, this example produces no bookmarks as `hyperref` is not loaded. Perhaps start over, make a complete example that actually compiles and displayes your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention it but i 've loaded the xspace  package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine. The key is that stuff that ends up in the bookmarks needs to be expandable.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{foo\xspace} 
\newcommand{\fooo}{fooo\xspace} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section about \foo}
\section{Another section about \fooo}
\end{document}
```